# Remove part of a tag in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I noticed a typo in multiple HTML tags in my DOM. Chrome and Edge browser ignores the typo and loads the image however Internet Explorer does not load the image at all.

Is there a script I can apply to remove the `src="<img` part of the tag?

```
<a href="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/feestverlichting-voor-de-achtertuin/"><img src="<img width="806" height="605" src="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin.jpg 806w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-152x114.jpg 152w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-768x576.jpg 768w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-253x190.jpg 253w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-506x380.jpg 506w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-600x450.jpg 600w, https://www.prikkabelled.nl/wp-content/uploads/Feestverlichting-voor-in-de-achtertuin-200x150.jpg 200w" sizes="(max-width: 806px) 100vw, 806px" /></a>
```

I know how to get all the elements using:

```
jQuery( "img.attachment-post-thumbnail" );
```

But now I am wondering how to remove the `src="<img`  from each element in the array returned.

Comment: Any kind of typing software has a search and replace function. So what is the problem?

Comment: Why do you want to modify the html source rather than get the problem fixed by the provider of the page?  Any custom work you do will potentially cause breakage later when they fix the bug.

Comment: Or is your solution to keep the wrong code and use JavaScript to change it as the page is loaded? Very bad practice. What if someone has JavaScript off?

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes: I think through PHP somehow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there are a few ways that can achieve this:

### method 1

`.removeAttr()` - removes attribute based on what's passed. e.g. `$('.class').removeAttr('src')`

### method 2

using a $.each to loop through then using `$(this)`

```
$('.class').each(function()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('src')
})
```

### method 3

using `.attr` - you can use this to set and remove attributes like so:

```
$('.class').attr('key', 'value');
//e.g.
$('.class').attr('src', 'www.google.com')
//or more for you
$('.class').attr('src', '')
```

I think you can use `.prop` in the same was `.attr`